# DNS Nameserver Error

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

Sorry I am new to this DNS jargon so the following question might sound obvious.

I have a VPS server and I am using third party dns server for managing DNS. My DNS provider had given me his own name servers which I replaced with my own using vanity name servers.

Everything is working fine and I also have updated glue records and name servers at my domain registrar. But when I run a DNS test I get following error.

```
Inconsistent glue for name server ns2.domain.com.
The address of a name server differed from the child and the parent. This is a configuration error and should be corrected as soon as possible.
```

Error explanation.

Inconsistent glue for name server.

```
Pingdom: On at least one of the parent-side a name server listed, there was an A or AAAA record and a record with the same name but different content was found on at least one of the child-side name servers.
```

I can't understand what's causing this error? Is this with my DNS provider or my domain registrar?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple.

For the name `ns2.domain.com`, you have one A (or AAAA) record in your zone, and one glue record in the TLD's zone.  They point to different addresses.

The glue record is set up by your registrar.  The other one is set up by you in your DNS configuration.  If the address you have set for the ns2 host yourself is right, let your registrar know they need to update the glue records for your domain (and give them the new IP).  If it is wrong, change the A or AAAA record for your ns2 host to match what is in the glue.

You can find what is in the glue record by querying the TLD nameservers.  Here is an example for `com.` on linux:

```
dig @m.gtld-servers.net in ns google.com
```

This will typically return an additional section with the A records for the nameservers.  You could also change the query to be more direct:

```
dig @m.gtld-servers.net in a ns1.google.com
```